# How to remove elements from array on the basis of subarray

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have two arrays in following format:

Arr1: [{name: 'TenG', id: 'd7cf4b5c-42ec-40fc-9b4e-b1600963ff37', group: 'add'}, ....]

Arr2: [{name: 'TenG, id: 'd7cf4b5c-42ec-40fc-9b4e-b1600963ff37', group: 'selected', category: undefined}, .....]

I want to keep all the elements of Arr1 which are not part of Arr2... I am shortlisting the data on the basis of group but seems the condition not coming right. please help on condition.

Sharing my code snippet for reference:

```
var tmpArr = [];
interfaces.filter((item) =>{
    selectedInterfaces.some((key=> (item.group!==key.group && tmpArr.push(item))))
})

console.log(tmpArr);
```

The result is coming as empty array in JSX. Thank you in advance for help !!

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: try this `selectedInterfaces.some(key=> item.group!==key.group && tmpArr.push(item) )`

Comment: Couple of observations. **1)** On the `.filter()` --> `interfaces.filter((item) => { return ...`. When using curly braces for arrow-function, one must use explicit `"return ...."`. **2)** [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) isn't typically used to `push` items into array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const tmpArr = interfaces.filter(item1 => {
  return selectedInterfaces.every(item2 => item1.group !== item2.group)
})
```

You can also use [lodash.differenceBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceBy) for that:

```
import differenceBy from 'lodash/differenceBy'

const tmpArr = differenceBy(interfaces, selectedInterfaces, 'group')
```